# Is it possible to chain an arbitrary number of v[global]?

Tags: vimscript

I am trying to execute the following:

```
exe 'v/' .. g:pattern1 .. '/ | v/' .. g:pattern2 .. '//'
```

where `g:pattern1` and `g:pattern2` are regular expressions, but what happen is that in the returned text only `g:pattern1` is excluded.

If I run them individually i.e.:

```
exe 'v/' .. g:pattern1 .. '/' 
exe 'v/' .. g:pattern2 .. '/'
```

they both work.

I wonder if it is possible to chain multiple `:v` (and also `g:`) commands through `|`.

EDIT: To better explain what I want to achieve consider the following text:

```
banana, apple
apple, banana

apple
```

and assume that it is loaded in the current buffer.

I want that:

1. the returned text from a command that include a chain of `v` similar to the one I posted at the beginning of this question has: a) all the blank lines removed; b) all the lined starting with `apple` removed
2. The returned text as per point 1. shall be redirected to a  register (say register `a`)

The solution that I was thinking looked like the following

```
vim9script

var pattern1 = '^\s*$' 
var pattern2 = '^apple'

redir @a  
silent exe 'v/' .. pattern1 .. '/ | v/' .. pattern2 .. '//'
redir END
```

that that does not work as it resemble the case I wrote at the beginning of the post that, as said, does not work.

I am not interested in alternative solutions that:

a) Modify the buffer,

b) Require the creation of scratch or temporary buffer/file.

Comment: What is your goal, exactly?

Comment: I edited the question. I hope it is now more clear.

Comment: XY for the loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem description:

1. remove all the empty lines
2. remove all the lines starting with apple
3. I don't want to modify the buffer
4. I don't want to create any scratch or temporary buffer/file
5. I want to store the text with the removed lines a register (say register a)

is a mess and I believe this is because you can't think clearly about what you are doing:

- you mention "empty lines" while your pattern says "blank line",
- #1 and #2 are in direct contradiction with #3,
- you rely almost solely on (poorly understood) Ex commands in a script,
- and the worst sin of all… you include your broken solution, making the whole thing a clear XY problem.

Anyway, here is a slightly reworked description of your problem, **without the misguided step that you took to solve it**:

> I want to store the text of the current buffer, without the blank lines and without the lines that start with `apple`, into a register (say register `a`).

Now that we have a clear problem, we can try to figure out how to solve it in a smart way. And, since we are in a script, we will try to do it with, well… *scripting*.

It is generally a good idea to split a large, difficult problem into a bunch of smaller, easier ones so that's what we are going to do…

### Problem #1:

> I want to **store the text** of the current buffer, without the blank lines and without the lines that start with `apple`, **into a register (say register `a`)**.

Storing arbitrary text in a register is done with `:help setreg()`:

```
vim9script
var myText = 'foobar'
setreg('a', myText)
```

It is even possible to give a list to `setreg()` to store multiline text without having to mess with EOLs and such:

```
vim9script
var myLines = ['foo', bar']
setreg('a', myLines)
```

### Problem #2:

> I want to store **the text of the current buffer**, without the blank lines and without the lines that start with `apple`, into a register (say register `a`).

Getting the content of the current buffer in a list is done with `:help getline()`:

```
vim9script
var myLines = getline(1, '$')
```

### Problem #3:

> I want to store the text of the current buffer, **without the blank lines and without the lines that start with `apple`**, into a register (say register `a`).

Removing items from a list if they match a given criteria is done with `:help filter()`. Our list is a list of lines so we can use it to remove unwanted lines:

```
vim9script
var myLines = getline(1, '$')
    \ ->filter('v:val !~ "^apple"')
    \ ->filter('v:val !~ "^\s*$"')
```

### Solution

Storing the filtered content of the current buffer in a register is thus as simple as:

```
vim9script
var myLines = getline(1, '$')
    \ ->filter('v:val !~ "^apple"')
    \ ->filter('v:val !~ "^\s*$"')
setreg('a', myLines)
```

Comment: Thanks. Btw, having confusing ideas and expressing poorly are often tied by causality, but unfortunately it is not always the case. I am going to edit my question to improve clarity. But again, thanks for your reply. I was thinking to use pure script but I don't think I could ever find the :h filter() function. Now I know.

Comment: Well, actually that was my biggest wondering about scripting: how to manipulate list, dictionaries, etc. I learned how to move stuff around through the various setline(), getbufline(), etc. but I never understood how to change stuff, so I always relied on exe or normal. Now I learned this filter function. Good.

Comment: Don't "wonder", ask Vim: `:help function-list`, `:help list-functions`, `:help dict-functions`, etc.

Comment: I know. The majority I learned is from there. But the docs is huge and overwhelming. I checked under text functions and strings function before…

Answer (score 0):

I believe you miss the second `exe`:

```
exe 'v/' .. g:pattern1 .. '/' | exe 'v/' .. g:pattern2 .. '/'
```

Comment: Hum, it does not seem to work... This will consider twice the current buffer, whereas I want the output of the first v to be used as input of the second v without changing the current buffer. I edited my question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your demand correctly. Even if you don't chain the `:v` command the first already modify the buffer. Maybe an example would help us.

Comment: I'll prepare an example and I will post it (not now though!). ;)

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: use @romainl solution

### Is it possible to chain an arbitrary number of v[global]?

Sort of. The `|` is right out. From `:h E147`:

```
When the command is used recursively, it only works on one line.  Giving a
range is then not allowed. This is useful to find all lines that match a
pattern and do not match another pattern: >
    :g/found/v/notfound/{cmd}
This first finds all lines containing "found", but only executes {cmd} when
there is no match for "notfound".
```

So for your case you can technically do:

```
:v/^\s*$/v/^apple/
```

### Can we do a bit better?

We can do a bit better by flipping some of the logic slightly. From not matching an empty line to match a line with a non-whitespace character, `\S`. Now it becomes

```
:g/\S/v/^apple/
```

You can then use your `:redir @a` tricks to capture the content into a register.

There are some other considerations though. Often using ex commands like this will modify various bits of Vim's state. In this case the current search pattern, `@/`, register. Which means you need to use `:keeppatterns`

### A more interesting question?!

I think the more interesting question is can you do this with a *single* pattern and `:global`/`:vglobal` command

Vim has some interesting pattern matching operators as well as look aheads/behinds. Using `\&` and a negative lookbehind you can do this in a single pattern

As fun as it would be to create such a pattern and explain it, Vim also ships with `:LogiPat` which can aid in making such patterns. See `:h :LogiPat`

Your pattern can be created using `:LogiPat "\S"&!"^apple"` which sets the search register to:

```
\%(.*\S.*\&^\%(\%(^apple\)\@!.\)*$\)
```

You can also use the `LogiPat()` function if you rather not mutate the search register.

Note: `:LogiPat` has some limitations so not every set of patterns will work